# How to load mesibo pending file message?

Tags: android, kotlin, mesibo

I want to try load mesibo pending image

[image]

I was looking the sample code in [github](https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/dcf866a162903669aecec0e79f95a54adbf2ef00/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MessagingFragment.java#L1468), but it didn't works and still show pending download file, here is the code
[image]

Comment: The possible reason could be that file transfer is failing. Check msg.getFile().url to ensure that the URL is valid. Also, if you have set up your file transfer handler, you may want to check there. In addition, check that if you need to update isVisible  after starting the file transfer.